# How to turn off iPhone 3G without using power button?

Tags: iphone

I've looked up various answers, but none of them worked. One involved squeezing the corner near the power button while pressing it, the other involved going into Settings > General > Accessibility but I don't have Accessibility menu for some reason.

I need to turn the phone off to jailbreak it. Anyone know of other methods? Perhaps a command in cmd might turn it off?

Comment: Did you check the jailbreak instructions to see whether you are not required to also use the power button as part of the jailbraking process?

Comment: It says I need to power it off after plugging it into my pc. The problem is my power off button doesn't work.

Comment: Got that. But if you now find a way to power it off in this specific situation only, this will not help you if need to power it off again further down during the jailbraking process. So better double-check.

Comment: Should I just click next next next on redsn0w even though the phone isn't plugged in just to see?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I looked at what redsn0w asks you to do, and it needs me to press the power button again during the process of installation. I guess I can't jailbreak my phone =/